# Error resolving jhipster dependency in kotlin enabled project

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, kotlin

My spring boot project which uses [jhipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/) is having issue resolving one of its dependencies:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.github.jhipster:jhipster-framework:2.0.6.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve io.github.jhipster:jhipster-framework:2.0.6.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/github/jhipster/jhipster-framework/2.0.6/jhipster-framework-2.0.6.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/github/jhipster/jhipster-framework/2.0.6/jhipster-framework-2.0.6.pom'. Received status code 409 from server: 

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/github/jhipster/jhipster-framework/2.0.6/jhipster-framework-2.0.6.pom'. Received status code 409 from server: 
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
3:21:15 PM: Task execution finished 'assemble'.
```

For some reason it's asking me to compile offline when it's unable to resolve the jhipster library. Any ideas?

I configured my project to [compile with kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/spring-boot-restful.html) but I don't think this is the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to jcenter and search jhipster-framework, https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/io.github.jhipster%3Ajhipster-framework, there isn't a version 2.0.6. The latest version is 2.0.8.

Comment: I changed the version number and now it's fixed! Something weird must have happened when I generated the project in jhipster.